# Reset permissions on xcode app m1 my device

Tags: flutter, xcode

I use xcode and "my device" on m1. I used flutter gallery plugin in my app and press "never allow" on first time. I getting now:

[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(photo_access_denied, The user did not allow photo access., null, null)

How I can reset permissions? I can change bundle name but I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Apple menu  > System Settings, click Privacy & Security  in the sidebar, then click **Photos** on the right.